# @dl php causes error

Tags: php, php-extension

A page of my site is stuck in these codes:

```
if (@dl("gmp.so")) { 
    echo '**';
    $loaded = true;
    break;
}
else
    echo '%%';
```

no echo is happend. It seems the problem is because of @dl . php5-gmp is install on the server.

How can I debug it ??

Comment: Remove the `@`, for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '@' disables the PHP Notices/Warnings/Errors. Remove the '@' and PHP will tell you what's wrong.

From php.net

```
This function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3.
```

Comment: after removing @ it gives this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl()

Comment: Since the function has been removed, you're trying to call a nonexistent function. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Barmar: a replacement for that nonexistent function and I found it.